# How to prevent starting the operating system’s associated program when I download xls files in python?

Tags: python, excel

I need to download many xls files from a web site. As you know, there is webbrowser.open function that I can use. In fact, it works very well but each time a file is downloaded, the operating system’s associated program (Excel) starts and lead my pc to fill the RAM.
How can I prevent opening Excel when the browser downloads files?

Comment: You can use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` function to download files.

Comment: works great!! Thank you!!!